# What is the tall red flower in this photo?

Tags: identification, flowers

This is supposed to be a pollinator attracting entance:

[image]

What is the name of the red flower?

I have never seen it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flower is a Monarda didyma. There are lots of hybrids: Jacob Cline, Gardenview Scarlet, Squaw, Cambridge Scarlet, etc. It's definitely a pollinator-attracting flower.